# Андроид. Управление scrollVIew

Tags: android, java, прокрутка, view

В общем проблема такая: внутри скрол вьюва лежит imageView с определёным обработчиком касаний. И один из жестов - движение пальцем снизу вверх. Но вместо этого жест перехватывает скроллер и экран прокручивается. Как сделать так, чтобы при проведении пальцем именно по этой картинке работал обработчик вместо скрола?

Comment: Написать свой класс `ScrollView` (наследовать) в котором переопределить этот жест - как вариант...

Comment: Бьюсь с той же самой проблемой. Только у меня Multi Touch по картинке, на отдельном активити работает, а вот на скрол вью ни в какую...

Comment: Да я тоже так подумал, переопределяю метод onTouchEvent, возвращаю false но всё равно не поддаётся никакой обработке всё что внутри...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я НАШЁЛ РЕШЕНИЕ!!!
В общем поэксперементировал с разными методами. Простым языком. Нужно создать свой класс, расширяющий ScrollView, и переопределить в нём метод onInterceptTouchEvent, написав ему всего одну единую строчку "return false". И всё =)

Comment: Ну я же говорил... :)